# Groff, mom - table is wider than the page width

Tags: groff

I have a table that is wider than the page width. How can I change the font size or table width so that it fits on the page? The second question is, how do I set the table in portrait orientation?

Here is a part from the alpha.csv file

```
alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,Zeta,Eta,Theta
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Part of the csv files longer as 800 lines. The name of the csv file is alpha.csv.
.TS H
center, allbox, tab(,);
c s s s s s s s
c c c c c c c c
c c c n n n n n .
This is the line with I can see on all pages
_
.TH
.so alpha.csv
.TE
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try

1) Renaming your column headers

2) Change the font point size for the headers

```
.TS H
center, allbox, tab(,);
cp-4 s s s s s s s
c c c c c c c c
c c c n n n n n .
```

3) Use all lower case for headers (upper case takes up more width)

4) Change your table to list text vertically instead of horizontally, so the header columns only take one char width each

5) Rotate your table so that the headers 'alpha, beta, ...' will appear as the first column